# How to correctly export and require in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, require

I read a tutorial about export/require in node/express and wonder if someone could explain to me with my example:
   why is my routing in app.js not working? What would I have to export and require to make it work? Thanks a lot!

index.js:

```
    'use strict'

    var express = require('express');

    var app = express();
    module.exports = app;

    var PORT = process.env.PORT || 1337;
        app.listen(PORT, function() {
        console.log('Server is listening!');
    })
```

app.js:

```
    var express = require('express');
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    var path = require('path');
    var app = express();
    //var app=require('./index.js');
    module.exports = function() {
        app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../public')));
        app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../browser')));
    }
```

Comment: What exactly doesn't work?  What URL do you expect to work and what happens when you try it?

Comment: when I had the entire code in only 1 file, it worked- I statically served my index.html file which is located in my public folder through app.use. When I separated the code into 2 files, it doesn't work anymore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your example will not work correctly at least because you declared two separate express servers in both files `var app = express()`.
2. This code is not the most suitable for practice in exporting/requiring because such servers initializations are usually placed in one file.

But anyway, if you would like to use this example and make it work, let's do in in this way:

> ./ index.js

```
'use strict'

var express = require('express');
var setupServing = require('./setupServing.js'); //import our function
var PORT = process.env.PORT || 1337;

var app = express(); //create express app
setupServing(app); //call imported function to config our app

app.listen(PORT, function() { //start
    console.log('Server is listening!');
})
```

> ./ setupServing.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
//export function which can configure static serve for app
module.exports = function(app) { //take app as an argument
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../public')));
}
```

Note that this example still is not logical enough and I don't think you will face such code in any real project, but anyway it will work and demonstrate exporting/requiring in nodejs.

Comment: Thank you! Can you explain to me a few things- why is it bad practice to separate middleware routes and where I start my server?I actually saw this somewhere and thought maybe thats good to have the starting point (starting server only) in one file and rest elsewhere. Also, you required the routes file but if I export (module.exports = app) then can't I require the index.js file and use app for app.use ... ? Yours works so I m just trying to understand it all. Thanks :)

Comment: It is nice practice to store all your routes and middlewares in the separate folders. Then you require middlewares to route files and use particular middlewares for particular routes.
Your example actually has no any routes. It is just a static server which is serving files from 'public' directory.

Comment: Check this for further examples and explanations:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/routes