# How to restructure NodeJS file

Tags: javascript, node.js

I started a NodeJS application and it has grown arms and legs and become huge. All the code was written in one file and now I'd like to separate it out but am confused with the examples at [NodeJs.org (modules)](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_modules_commonjs_modules).

I have `index.js` which contains my code presently, and lets say for example I want to put all my frequently used functions in to a library for easier maintenance:

```
/
  index.js
  functions
   |_ functionLibrary.js
```

In `functionLibrary.js` lets also say, a lot of those functions call my logging script, which I also want to separate out so create `loggingInit.js` too.

```
/
  index.js
  functions
   |_ functionLibrary.js
   |_ loggingInit.js
```

`loggingInit.js` contains the following:

```
//Logging functionality
'use strict';
const { createLogger, format, transports, addColors } = require('winston');
require('winston-daily-rotate-file');
var fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const logDir = '/var/log/myNodeProject';
if (!fs.existsSync(logDir)) { fs.mkdirSync(logDir); }

const customLevels = { error: 0,warn: 1,info: 2,success: 3 }
const customColors = { error: 'bold red', warn: 'yellow', info: 'blue', success: 'bold white greenBG' };

addColors(customColors);

const dailyRotateFileTransport = new transports.DailyRotateFile({
    filename: `${logDir}/%DATE%.log`,
    handleExceptions: true,
    format: format.colorize({ all: true }),
    datePattern: 'YYYY-MM-DD'
});

const logger = createLogger({
    levels: customLevels,
    level: 'success',
    format: format.combine(
        format.timestamp({ format: 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss' }),
        format.splat(),
        format.printf(function (info) {
            if (typeof info.message === 'object') {
              info.message = JSON.stringify(info.message, null, 3)
            }
            
            return `${info.timestamp} ${info.level}: ${info.message}`;
        })
    ),
    transports: [dailyRotateFileTransport],
    exitOnError: false
});
```

What do I need to add to so that the logging functionality can be accessed by `functionLibrary` and further to `functionLibrary` so that it can be read by `index.js`?

Comment: `require()` your own files and assign to `exports` inside them. Please try the code outlined in the docs first, until you actually get stuck with errors. Best try it in a separate, very simple project.

Comment: Dupe: [How to correctly export and require in node js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46494810/how-to-correctly-export-and-require-in-node-js)

Comment: Thanks, so require is basically 'include'? I think it's the exporting that I'm not getting to grips with

Comment: For example, functionLibrary.js and index.js both reference `logger`, I'm assuming I need export logger from loggingInit.js as well as requiring loggingInit.js, so it can be called?

Comment: Say you have a function L that lives in file A. That's where you export it, in file A (and only there). In any other file B, C, D where you need function L, you require it (from file A).

Comment: Ok... I think I've gotten it. The NodeJS examples seem over complicated, or maybe I've just been looking at it for too long

Comment: Basically, when you do `module.exports = x;` in a file, to get x in another file, you do `const x = require(./xfile);`

Comment: And you can require the same file as many times as needed, in other files?

Comment: Yes, it's basically put together into one single script for execution.